# Unsure on how to connect these bed frame legs to the frame

Tags: woodworking

Im undertaking a project to build a king size bed. I have the connections for the bed figured out with the exception of the legs.
Essentially the bed can be broken down into three parts:
1- Headboard
2 - Frame with mattress supports
3- Legs
I thought of using the screw bolt as attached but I am unsure if this will be strong enough to hold, especially for bed rocking.

I am also unable to use glue as this bed will need to be disassembled.

Open to suggestions thanks for your help

[image: Bed frame]
[image: Bed frame 2]
[image: Screw bolt]

Comment: Do you want it to appear exactly as shown or would using corner braces to secure the legs be acceptable?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. I will be using corner braces like this link https://www.amazon.com.au/Socell-No-Mortise-Connectors-Headboards-Footboards/dp/B07P1N34WQ

Im unsure of how to attach the "square frame" to the two legs

Comment: @AndrewMorton I just re read your comment. Preferably I would like this to appear as is. Would the corner braces be strong enough? The wood I will use is called Victorian ash

Comment: Suggestion: Add 2 perpendicular "legs" (possible recessed) to form a corner braced base

Comment: I apologize that I don't have time for a proper answer right now, but this sort of thing: https://www.amazon.com/Furniture-Galvanized-Carbon-Connector-Fastener/dp/B071YMF3CM (google term: cross dowel bolt) with the bolt coming up through the bottom of the leg to the cross dowel on the interior of the sides. Additionally, I think you'd want a small (2x4" or 38x89mm) between the legs (in the middle, vertically aligned) that will keep the legs from folding over when the bed is rocked back and forth.

Comment: Other benefit of the 2x4 is that it adequately supports the middle beam.

Comment: @Molecule6953 you could just screw the mattress supports to the "feet" that go across, and rest the box frame on top of the feet, then screw the box to the mattress supports using 90º brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Aloysius, the Cross Dowel Bolt is a Good Option. You would put the ‘nut’ in the leg, maybe mid way+ down from the top, The frame has a hole for the Screw, the leg has a hole for the nut. Then you put in the screw though the frame, through 1/2 the leg, into the nut pulling it tight to the frame.

This is also how my Frame is attached to my Head/foot boards.

A Video on how to install. You won’t need the Heavy Duty Bolt size he has with that Head, they make others with more off a flange head and not as bulky (sticking out) [Installing Heavy Cross Dowel and Bolts](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Y-xZx9M0ros)

Comment: Thank you, when the screw goes into the frame, is there a way to make it not show a hole, My understanding is that I will need to drill a hole into the top of the frame in order to instal this joint?

Comment: Mine have a Dowel Plug in them. Though they are visible from the footboard.   Yours should be on the horizontal support under the bed frame. You could counter sink the head of the screw so its more flush. but would not see it as its under the Mattress. 

The hole in the Leg for nut cloud be made so  you could put a dowel cap on it or face to the inside so it's not as visible.